# Is alignment of struct types defined in C?

Tags: c, struct, memory-alignment

I know that the members in a C struct are aligned to whatever boundary they need.

```
struct S {
  uint8_t ui8;
  /* invisible padding here */
  uint32_t ui32;
};
```

My question is if the alignment of instances of `struct S` is defined?

```
struct S my_s;
```

Is alignment of `my_s` defined? Does it matter if `struct S` would have `ui32` as its first member?

I have searched but only found info on struct member alignment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Answer:** Not in C99. Yes in C11. Refer to the [answer from unwind](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28562161/2410359).

On C99 in practice on all known platforms you can determine alignment of a type:

```
#include <stddef.h> //Defines offsetof(.,.) 

#define alignmentof(TYPE) offsetof(struct { char w; TYPE v;},v)
```

The C standard specifies little regarding on how structures may be padded except that it's OK, they can't be padded at the beginning but can be padded in the middle and end and must align correctly in an array without inter-element padding.

In practice no one (I've found) has come forward with a real platform where they are other than either not padded (so called packed) or padded minimally to obey the alignment of the data types on the underlying hardware.

The natural padding routine is:

1. Place the first member at the start (this is a strict requirement).
2. Minimally pad up to the alignment of the next member and insert it.
3. Repeat for all remaining members.
4. Minimally add end padding to make sure the `sizeof` of the `struct` is a multiple of the alignment of the most strictly aligned member.

As mentioned, in practice if padding takes place this is what happens (as far as my informal survey has ever found).

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it will have an alignment requirement, and yes it will depend on the type(s) of the member(s) of the `struct`.

The C11 draft spec says:

> Complete object types have alignment requirements which place restrictions 
>   on the addresses at which objects of that type may be allocated.

and:

> The alignment requirement of a complete type can be queried using an 
>   `_Alignof` expression.

Comment: `it might depend on the type(s) of the member(s)`, It might? What's the other conditions?

Comment: @nouney It can also be made to depend on  use of `#pragma`s and such, but that's being overly cautious. I edited, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

yes ...

```
struct S {
  uint8_t ui8;
  /* invisible padding here */
  uint32_t ui32;
};
```

has size = 8

the structure contains a 4 byte uint32_t so the `struct` would be aligned to 4 byte

lets say the it starts from 0x0
so lets see

```
0x0 = ui8
0x1 = padding
0x2 = padding
0x3 = padding
0x4 = ui32
```

if lets say we add a uint32_t at the start then it would become... the struct would seem like

```
struct S {
  uint32_t ui32_2;
  uint8_t ui8;
  /* invisible padding here */
  uint32_t ui32;
};
```

then

```
0x0 = ui32_2
0x4 = ui8
0x5 = padd
0x6 = padd
0x7 = padd
0x8 = ui32
```

the structure keep the alignment equal to the highest size member it contains. in this case the struct will always begin at address

> address %4 == 0

Comment: Almost. Some platforms don't align data in which case the padding would disappear. It's also possible the alignment of `uint32_t` could be 2 in which case 2 fewer padding bytes would be required. I don't off hand know of a platform that aligns `uint32_t` on two byte boundaries! But it is possible. Upvoted anyway for such a detailed answer.

Comment: @DanAllen: The 68000 used in the original Macintosh would trap if an attempt were made to access a 16-bit or 32-bit quantity on an address that was not 16-bit aligned, but could satisfy 32-bit requests from any pair of consecutive 16-bit words without regard for 32-bit alignment.  Such a design made it easy to have code e.g. draw a 16-pixel object at any X offset by using a 32-bit load to fetch the background, drawing the object shifted by 0 to 15 bits, and then using a 32-bit store.